Pairs of infinite subsets of natural numbers that intersect on an infinite set give the same property to triples?
Let $A \subseteq P(\mathbb{N})$ such that $A$ is infinite and for each pair $B,C \in A$ then $B \cap C$ is infinite, this implies that for any triple $B,C,D \in A$, $B\cap C \cap D \neq \varnothing$? Or what set $A$ would work as a counterexample?
I've been a bit stuck on this and I haven't come up with a counterexample so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Another question I have is that if any element in $A$ is such that it contains segments of natural numbers of any length then for any $B,C \in A$ then $B\cap C \neq \varnothing$

The elements of $A$ are natural numbers, not sets. Do you mean $A\subseteq P( \mathbb N)?$

You're right I edited the question

I also added another question, that's my only intuition of an A that might have the desired property

What do you. mean by segments?

A segment of length $N$ of natural numbers is a subset that has $N$ consecutive natural numbers

Question 1
Counterexample: divide $\mathbb{N}$ into three infinite subsets $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ and let
$$\mathcal{A} = \{ A_1 \cup A_2, A_2 \cup A_3, A_3 \cup A_1 \} \cup \{ \{ m \in \mathbb{N} : m \geqslant n \} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}.$$
Then every two elements of $\mathcal{A}$ have infinite intersection, but the first three sets above have empty intersection.
Question 2
The answer is negative - let $\mathcal{A}$ consist of two sets: one containing all numbers with even number of digits, and the other containing the numbers with odd number of digits. Each of these sets contains arbitrarily long segments, but their intersection is empty.

Thanks, these are nice counterexamples but I asked when A is infinite, are there any counterexamples there?

$\mathcal{A}$ in the answer to the first question is infinite. For the other question it was unclear if you wanted an infinite family, but even so it can be done. Partition $\mathbb{N}$ into infinitely many infinite sets $D_i$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $$A_i = { n \in \mathbb{N} : n \text{ has } k \text{-many digits with } k \in D_i }.$$ Then $A_i \cap A_j = \varnothing$ for $i \neq j$, but all these sets contain arbitrarily long segments.

Oh yeah you're right thanks

Wow that was quick.
